# Is original review box necessary on post when using All In One Schema Rich Snippets?

Tags: wordpress, rich-snippets, user-reviews

I want to add reviews to my posts and wish to use All In One Schema Rich Snippets plugin.

Using the plugin shows a review box at the end of the post.

I am using Thrive architect and will add a review box from that to the post.

So my question is If I disable the review box of Plugin and show review box from Thrive architect, with the same details, Will that be fine?